# Difference between SQL Server 2005 & 2008

Tags: sql-server

Can anyone give me some description about differences between SQL Server 2008 and SQL Server 2005?

Are there changes comes in update query or any new feature in 2008 version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most important, in my opinion, are:

- `MERGE`
- Chained `OUTPUT`
- Ability to pass table variables into the stored procedures
- Native support for materialized path (`hierarchyid`)
- Filtered (partial) indexes

Comment: And it has word auto-completion, like IntelliSense. :)

Comment: @Felipe: this is a feature of `SSMS`, not `SQL Server` itself.

Answer (score 3):

[What's New In Sql Server 2008](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb500435%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) - MSDN reference, comprehensive listing

[What's New In Sql Server 2008 R2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb500435%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - same, but for 2008 R2 version

[What's New In Sql Server 2012](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb500435%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) - same, but for 2012 version

Comment: do you have the same for SQL Server 2008 **R2** as welL??